# Java Spring 4 on failed validation, instead of rendering form it simply prints view name

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-validator

I am from PHP world and trying to learn Java Spring framework in spare time. I was doing good until I decided to add validation to a form. Below is my code.

```
package com.invokedynamic.spring;


import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.validation.Valid;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import com.invokedynamic.spring.User;

/**
 * Handles requests for the application home page.
 */
@Controller
public class RestController {

  private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RestController.class);
  private Map<String, User> users = new HashMap<String, User>();

  public RestController() {
    // pre-initialize the list of issuers available ...

      users.put("pinkal", new User("pinkal", "pinkal123", "pinkal@gmail.com", "USA"));
      users.put("mahesh", new User("mahesh", "mahesh123", "mahesh@gmail.com", "USA"));
  }

  /**
   * Simply selects the home view to render by returning its name.
   */
  @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public String home(Locale locale, Model model) {
    logger.info("Welcome home! The client locale is {}.", locale);

    Date date = new Date();
    DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.LONG, DateFormat.LONG, locale);

    String formattedDate = dateFormat.format(date);

    model.addAttribute("serverTime", formattedDate );

    return "status";
  }

  @RequestMapping(value="/users", method=RequestMethod.GET)
  @ResponseBody
  public Map<String, User> getAllUsers() {
    logger.info("Inside getAllUsers() method...");

    return users;
  }

  @RequestMapping(value="/user/{username}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
  @ResponseBody
  public User getUserByUsername(@PathVariable("username") String username) {
      User user = users.get(username);

    if (user != null) {
      logger.info("Inside sgetUserByUsername, returned: " + user.toString());
    } else {
      logger.info("Inside getUserByUsername, ticker: " + username + ", NOT FOUND!");
    }
    return user;
  }

  @RequestMapping(value="/user/delete/{username}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
  @ResponseBody
  public User deleteIssuerByTicker(@PathVariable("username") String username) {
      User user = users.remove(username);

    if (user != null) {
      logger.info("Inside deleteIssuerByTicker, deleted: " + user.toString());
    } else {
      logger.info("Inside deleteIssuerByTicker, ticker: " + username + ", NOT FOUND!");
    }
    return user;
  }

  @RequestMapping(value="/user/create", method=RequestMethod.GET)
  public ModelAndView addUser() {

    return new ModelAndView("addUser", "command", new User());
  }

  @RequestMapping(value="/user/addUser", method=RequestMethod.POST)
  @ResponseBody
  public String addUser(@Valid @ModelAttribute("user") User user, BindingResult result, Model model) {
      if (result.hasErrors()) {           
          return "addUser";
      }
    if (user != null) {
      logger.info("Inside addIssuer, adding: " + user.toString());
    } else {
      logger.info("Inside addIssuer...");
    }
    users.put(user.getUsername(), user);
    return "{\"success\":1}";
  }
}
```

On failed validation instead of rendering "addUser" view it simply prints "addUser" on screen. What am I doing Wrong? Full source can be seen [here](https://github.com/pinkal-vansia/Spring4RestAPI).

EDIT

If I remove `@ResponseBody` from `addUser` method as suggested by couple of answers below, I get

> HTTP Status 500 - java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither
>   BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'command'
>   available as request attribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are using `@ResponseBody` annotation.

When you use this annotation the data returned from here would be treated as data to be present in the body rather then treated as view name and be resolved by the `viewResolver`.

Also add the below attributes to your form tag as shown below

```
<f:form method="POST" action="addUser" commandName="user">
```

Comment: Thanks for takin time. But If I remove @ResponseBody , I get  java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'command' available as request attribute

Comment: Can you check what is the name of the command present in the view.

Comment: Thanks But I dont understand as I am still very new to Spring. Here is a link to my view. https://github.com/pinkal-vansia/Spring4RestAPI/blob/master/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views/addUser.jsp

Comment: in your adduser.jsp do add the attributes `modelAttribute="user" commandName="user"` to the form tag and try

Comment: Thanks. adding commandName="user" in form tag did the trick. It is working now. Can you please updated your answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of `@ResponseBody` annotation. Check this:

https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ResponseBody.html